# Match … character in rewrite rule with nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a problem, where someone has added a link to our site - but its getting cut off. I'm seeing in the log file, as:

```
/info-cry%E2%80%A6
```

Seeing as I know what that is mean't to be going to, I'm trying to create a rewrite rule for it in my nginx configuration for the site. I've tried both of the below:

```
rewrite ^/info-cry%E2%80%A6 https://example.com/info-cryptex-16gb-usb-drive-587.html permanent;
rewrite ^/info-cry… https://example.com/info-cryptex-16gb-usb-drive-587.html permanent;
```

..but it never matches (just shows our custom 404 page). Is there a way I can achieve this? I really want to get it working - as we are getting a lot of hits to the broken URL

Comment: Thanks @AndréBorie - unfortunately, we need that URL (and it gets into an infinite loop if you do a (.*)) . I manged to get it working using the below solution with the (*UTF8) flag in the location rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange. On Ubuntu 15.04's nginx 1.6.2 with all the default modules, I can do

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/foo… http://example.com permanent;
}
```

...and get the expected redirect.

Assuming you have reloaded nginx and disabled your browser cache, are you sure the rewrite is happening in a location block that matches `/info-cry…`? It's also possible that you [might need to prepend](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,224105,224164#msg-224164) `(*UTF8)` to a regex defining a location block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just checked, and I'm on `nginx version: nginx/1.6.2`, so looks like the latest. I just tested it in a private window (in FF), and still the same issue. In the end, tweaking the rule for the location did the trick: `if ($uri !~ (*UTF8)"\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css)$") {` . Thanks :)

Comment: Good to hear that worked for you! Since you're actually on the same nginx as me, I'll edit my answer to remove my incorrect assumption that you'd only need `(*UTF8)` if you were on an older version.